# what we should write when wikipedia wants "Page" from us

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

i'm trying to use wikipeida-API and get the contents(as HTML) of a page for example [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco) one

i am trying with Sandbox but there is a misteke. In [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Project%3aSandbox) page i'm writing **San Francisco** in **Page** section an it says *The page you specified doesn't exist*.Just like [that](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=San%20Francisco).(click **Make Request** and see it)

what should i write in this page section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write San Francisco to Page. there is nothing wrong. wrong thing is sandbox itself.
If you write San Francisco to page it gives you that url:

*/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=San%20Francisco*

add **en.wikipedia.org** to it and go to [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=San%20Francisco). See everything is fine.Sandbox gives you error cause it programmed wrong basically.

if you want that page as HTML:

```
<?php
$ip_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Los%20Angeles"), true);
?>


<html>
<body>
     <?php print_r($ip_data['parse']['text']['*'])  ?>
</body>
</html>
```